# Always Freeze mocks using AutoFixture, XUnit, and Moq

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, xunit.net, autofixture

I'm using AutoFixture, Moq, and XUnit extensions (`[Theory]` attribute) as described in this blog post http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/10/08/AutoDataTheorieswithAutoFixture.

I've noticed that most of unit tests look like this:

```
[Theory, AutoMoqData]
public void Test(
    [Frozen] Mock<IServiceOne> serviceOne,
    [Frozen] Mock<IServiceTwo> serviceTwo,

    MyClass classUnderTest)
{
    // Arrange
    serviceOne
        .Setup(m => m.Get(It.IsAny<int>()));

    serviceTwo
        .Setup(m => m.Delete(It.IsAny<int>()));

    // MyClass has a constructor with arguments for IServiceOne, and IServiceTwo
    // classUnderTest will use the two mocks specified above

    // Act
    var result = classUnderTest.Foo();

    // Assert
    Assert.True(result);
}
```

As opposed to always decorating the mocks with `[Frozen]`, is there a way to setup the fixture to always freeze mocks?

Here's the `AutoMoqData` attribute:

```
public class AutoMoqDataAttribute : AutoDataAttribute
{
    public AutoMoqDataAttribute()
        : base(new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization()))
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Although it's currently not built-in, it's easy to write a general purpose Decorator that freezes objects as they leave the AutoFixture Tree of Responsibility:

```
public class MemoizingBuilder : ISpecimenBuilder
{
    private readonly ISpecimenBuilder builder;
    private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<object, object> instances;

    public MemoizingBuilder(ISpecimenBuilder builder)
    {
        this.builder = builder;
        this.instances = new ConcurrentDictionary<object, object>();
    }

    public object Create(object request, ISpecimenContext context)
    {
        return this.instances.GetOrAdd(
            request,
            r => this.builder.Create(r, context));
    }
}
```

Notice that it Decorates another `ISpecimenBuilder`, but remembers all values before it returns them. If the same request arrives again, it'll return the memoized value.

While you can't *extend* `AutoMoqCustomization`, you can replicate what it does (it's only two lines of code), and use the `MemoizingBuilder` around it:

```
public class AutoFreezeMoq : ICustomization
{
    public void Customize(IFixture fixture)
    {
        if (fixture == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("fixture");

        fixture.Customizations.Add(
            new MemoizingBuilder(
                new MockPostprocessor(
                    new MethodInvoker(
                        new MockConstructorQuery()))));
        fixture.ResidueCollectors.Add(new MockRelay());
    }
}
```

Use this `AutoFreezeMoq` instead of `AutoMoqCustomization`. It will freeze all mocks, and all interfaces and abstract base classes created from those mocks.

```
public class AutoMoqDataAttribute : AutoDataAttribute
{
    public AutoMoqDataAttribute()
        : base(new Fixture().Customize(new AutoFreezeMoq()))
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Could you create one for NSubstitute? I'm currently evaluating using that over Moq. Here's my attempt: `fixture.Customizations.Add(
                new MemoizingBuilder(
                    new NSubstituteBuilder(
                        new MethodInvoker(
                            new NSubstituteMethodQuery()))));`

Comment: Looking at `AutoNSubstituteCustomization`, I think you need to add it to `fixture.ResidueCollectors` instead of `fixture.Customizations`, but otherwise it looks right. I haven't tested it, though. Does it work?

Comment: It worked when I added it either `fixture.ResidueCollectors` or `fixture.Customizations`. Not sure why though.

Comment: I noticed that for the `NSubstitute` setup in my comment, I still need to use `[Frozen]` on concrete classes to get the correct reference. Any idea why that is or if it's possible to have it freeze for concrete classes too?

Comment: IIRC, none of the Auto-mocking extensions mock concrete classes. This is by design. This post explains it in the context of AutoMoq, but AutoNSubstitute ought to be consistent with that behaviour too: http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/08/25/ChangingthebehaviorofAutoFixtureauto-mockingwithMoq

Comment: I have a concrete (`Configuration`) class defined in the test's parameters. The SUT (also inside parameter of the test) is being injected with the instance of `Configuration` specified. Placing `[Frozen]` around the `Configuration` parameter gives me the ability to modify it's behavior while inside the SUT.

Comment: Hey Mark, is there a way to make this handle delegates too? It seems that delegates don't get substituted and passed in.

Comment: IIRC, Moq doesn't do delegates, so the first step would be to find a Test Double library that does (I think Rhino Mocks do, but that's sort of defunct). The next step would be to write a filter that includes delegates when requested, but IIRC, AutoFixture already generates delegates for you.

Answer (score 3):

I ended up [copying code from the `AutoDataAttribute` class](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/blob/master/Src/AutoFixture.xUnit.net/AutoDataAttribute.cs#L87-L121) and modifying it to include a `FreezingCustomization`.

This is the resulting attribute.

```
public class AutoMoqDataAttribute : AutoDataAttribute
{
    public AutoMoqDataAttribute()
        : base(new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization()))
    {
    }

    public override IEnumerable<object[]> GetData(System.Reflection.MethodInfo methodUnderTest, Type[] parameterTypes)
    {
        var specimens = new List<object>();
        foreach (var p in methodUnderTest.GetParameters())
        {
            CustomizeFixture(p);
            if (p.ParameterType.GetInterfaces().Any(t => t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IMock<>)))
            {
                var freeze = new FreezingCustomization(p.ParameterType, p.ParameterType);
                this.Fixture.Customize(freeze);
            }
            var specimen = Resolve(p);
            specimens.Add(specimen);
        }

        return new[] { specimens.ToArray() };
    }

    private void CustomizeFixture(ParameterInfo p)
    {
        var dummy = false;
        var customizeAttributes = p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(CustomizeAttribute), dummy).OfType<CustomizeAttribute>();
        foreach (var ca in customizeAttributes)
        {
            var c = ca.GetCustomization(p);
            this.Fixture.Customize(c);
        }
    }

    private object Resolve(ParameterInfo p)
    {
        var context = new SpecimenContext(this.Fixture);
        return context.Resolve(p);
    }
}
```